# Google Play Services update warning when trying to use

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I try to use Google Play Services on my Android phone which is Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini (Android ver. 4.1.2) I am warned as `This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services` everytime I want to use Google Play Services (version 5.2.08).

My device's Play Services version is 5.0.89 and there is no update for it (I check it on Play Store for updates).

I also tried on Htc One X (version 4.2.2) and Play Store Services version is the same as Galaxy S3 Mini.

I tried using Play Services as `play-services:5.+` but this time I am not able to use `AdMob`.

Should I use Play Services as 5.+ and external jar for `AdMob` or is there another solution that I don't know?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use "+", specify your version.

Comment: Why @JaredBurrows? It is recommended by Google for Android Studio. (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: He is asking about Google Play Services. If you use "+": compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+' then it will pull in a beta SDK that is newer than the play version.

Answer (score 1):

Version 5.2.08 is the preview version and pertains to Android L. If your phone is running KitKat and below you have to revert to a previous version to allow Google Play Services to run.